# The integral of $\frac{1}{\tau_1-\tau_2}(e^{-t/\tau_1}-e^{-t/\tau_2})$

Tags: integration, derivatives, exponential-function

If we have

$$
\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{1}{\tau_1-\tau_2}(e^{-t/\tau_1}-e^{-t/\tau_2}),
$$

what is $x$, and what are the steps by which one comes to that solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
\int \frac{1}{\tau_1 - \tau_2}(e^{-t/\tau_1} - e^{-t/\tau_2}) dt
&= \frac{1}{\tau_1 - \tau_2}\int e^{-t/\tau_1} dt
- \frac{1}{\tau_1 - \tau_2}\int e^{-t/\tau_2} dt \\
&= \frac{-\tau_1}{\tau_1 - \tau_2} e^{-t/\tau_1} - \frac{-\tau_2}{\tau_1 - \tau_2} e^{-t/\tau_2} + C
\end{align*}$$

Since

$$ \int e^{-t/\tau_1} dt = -\tau_1 e^{-t/\tau_1} + C$$